# GRUB trouble (installing Ubuntu, dual-booting with OS X)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, live-usb

I want to be able to dual boot OS X and Ubuntu, but have run into an issue (GRUB).

Progress so far:

- I successfully got rEFInd working on El Capitan (disabled System Integrity Protection and Full Disk Encryption).
- I made a bootable USB using [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) with 16.04 on it. It's formatted as "exFAT" and apparently the last time it was modified was 31/12/1979. I used UNetbootin to make the bootable USB.
- I partitioned my SSD, so that I now have Macintosh HD and Untitled, both formatted as OS X Extended. I tried to just shrink my current partition as described in [How-To Geek's instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/)

  > Don’t create a new partition after shrinking your current partition  — just leave the space empty for now.

  but unfortunately the 40 GB partition always kept getting formatted as OS X extended instead of staying empty (also I actually asked for 40 GB but it became 39.22 GB).

When I shutdown and power on again, rEFInd is shown and I can see a picture of Linux's Tux among the icons. There's also a fallback option shown. After selecting Tux for Ubuntu, instead of seeing the Ubuntu installation, GRUB comes up stating

> "Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. for the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions."

I had a look at the options using tab, typing 'boot' seemed like a reasonable command but wasn't sure so I held the power button on my mac and did a hard shutdown.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully reached the Live USB desktop. It's all plain sailing from here.

**I solved it by formatting the USB as FAT instead of exFAT.**

I reformatted the 40 GB partition on my SSD as FAT too just in case.